# Objective C: globally available method

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm using the following implementation to check if there's s internet connection avaliable, and it's working fine, but because I'm gonna check for a internet connection a lot I think it's best for (BOOL)reachable method to be avaliable everywhere without rewriting it everytime. Because I'm new to iOS development I'm not sure how to do that. What's the best way to do that?

```
//
// SigninViewController.m
//

#import "Reachability.h"
#import "SigninViewController.h"

@implementation SigninViewController

...

- (IBAction)SigninTouchUpInside:(id)sender
{

    if ([self reachable])
    {
        NSLog(@"Reachable");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Not Reachable");
    }

}

- (BOOL)reachable {
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"enbr.co.cc"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(internetStatus == NotReachable) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Singleton Design Pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html) is exactly for that kind of usage

The best way to implement a singleton is by creating a class that inherits NSObject and declaring a `sharedInstance` class method that will return a unique instance of this class thanks to the GCD `dispatch_once` function *(so that calling `sharedInstance` will allocate the object only the first time, returning always the same object/instance on further calls)*

```
@interface ReachabilityService : NSObject
+ (id)sharedInstance;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) BOOL networkIsReachable;
@end


@implementation ReachabilityService
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static ReachabilityService *sharedInstance = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{ sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init]; });
    return sharedInstance;
}
- (BOOL)networkIsReachable
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"enbr.co.cc"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return (internetStatus != NotReachable);
}
@end
```

---

Another way to do it is to declare your method as a class method directly, as it won't use any instance variable or property. That is declaring directly `+ (BOOL)networkIsReachable` instead of `- (BOOL)networkIsReachable`, and avoid the use of the Singleton Pattern and the `sharedInstance` method itself.

```
@interface ReachabilityService : NSObject
+ (BOOL)networkIsReachable;
@end

@implementation ReachabilityService
+ (BOOL)networkIsReachable
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"enbr.co.cc"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return (internetStatus != NotReachable);
}
@end
```

Comment: Another way is to bundle it into a class that will encapsulate the details of your networking stack. Not necessarily a singleton, but not in the app delegat either, which I always consider a plus :) EDIT: another advantage is now you have an object to handle the reachability status change notifications and handle / communicate them as appropriate.

Comment: I edited my answer to propose an alternate way to do it, making it a class method as in this case the singleton does not have any ivar or property to handle. But I still prefer the Singleton approach and the "Service" model as you can then add a lot of stuff to it (like handling notifications of reachability changes as you suggest). I totally agree that putting this in the App Delegate is a bad conception choice.

Answer (score 3):

Make it a plain C function:

```
BOOL reachable()
{
    // implementation here
}
```

Declare it in a separate header file and implement it independently from any other class, so it can be used from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You could make it a method of your app delegate class. Since the method doesn't need to access any class properties, it could be a class method (declare with "+") rather than an instance method (declare with "-").

In yourAppDelegate.h:

```
+ (BOOL)reachable;
```

In yourAppDelegate.m:

```
+ (BOOL)reachable {
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"enbr.co.cc"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return (internetStatus == NotReachable);
}
```

To call the method:

```
#import "yourAppDelegate.h"
...
BOOL reachable = [YourAppDelegate reachable];
```

Comment: I suppose that the one that downvoted it thought that using the AppDelegate for this is not the best practice, as the AppDelegate is not made for this but for application events delegation. It is often a better design to create a dedicated singleton for this kind of purpose (the AppDelegate is a singleton by design because it is the delegate of UIApplication which is itself a singleton, but having a dedicated class for each functionality is more logical), or put the function in dedicated "utility.h/.m" files or alike (even if putting this code in the AppDelegate would obviously work anyway).